# 1980's Transistor ID & Silkscreen (German Automotive)

Tags: transistors, silkscreen

From the circuit board of a 1985 Volkswagen engine control unit...

I can't find the device itself based on the markings. Does the silkscreen help?

[image]

Comment: Probably not a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, actually it looks like this must be it:

http://www.datasheetspdf.com/PDF/BCX58/127619/1

Based on that datasheet, the silkscreen is indicating E - B - C (left to right).

Is that marking still in use today?